# How to increase size of the Spotlight search results window?

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight, settings

Is it possible to increase window width of the Spotlight search results under Mac OS X 10.6.6? I mean the semi-transparent "instant search result" window appearing at the top right corner under magnifying glass, not the Finder window.

The standard window is too narrow: longer file names or Dictionary word translations just don't fit there. Why not using more screen space for the search result?

Comment: You can't really do that, but good news is that OS X's new version, Lion, seems to have a wider result pane. Of course, as everything Lion related, it's subject to change. For an alternative, you can always try http://frovil.com/spotlaser.html but it's probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using 'Alfred' as search tool - It's free on the App Store and very flexible, and has a wider results view. If you try it, take a little time to get familiar with the options - I find it a fantastic time saver.

Answer (score 0):

There are [hacks](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/add-columns-to-spotlight-search-results.html) for the resultant Finder window but nothing for the actual results pane dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answers to the question (and moreover I am using 10.5), but you already know that if you hover over a result for a couple of seconds, it shows the complete file name and path, don't you?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It does help a little, but I would like to have more :) The whole idea of this spotlight search is to get results instantly. Otherwise one can open a finder search window or the Dictionary app...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Quicksilver.](http://qsapp.com/index.php) Note that it is still in beta, but it is a pretty stable beta. It is a little complicated to use, but it is more that just a replacement for Spotlight. It has smart capabilities, so it remembers what you typed recently. For me, I use Chrome a lot, so when I type "C" it automatically knows that I want Chrome. It also does provide dictionary results from dict.org and it displays them in a way that you can see them. Let me know if you do use this as it can be confusing for new users.